# Exporting AmXYChart to PNG

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I want to export charts to PNG. It works fine, except for `AmXYCharts`. It exports just the axes.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mHWw/)

Comment: please, check your fiddle in the meanwhile it has been solved.